# Why Is DataView or Int32Array, not treat underlying bytes as groups of integers

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to read integers from a buffer of bytes, accessing the values by their index. For instance, accessing i[0] would return the integer represented by the first four bytes of the buffer, i[1] would return the integer represented by the second four bytes, and so on.

```js
let b = Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

let i = new Int32Array(b)

expect(b.length).toBe(8)
expect(i.length).toBe(8 / 4)

expect(b[4]).toBe(1)
expect(i[1]).toBe(16)
```

As context, I get the buffer from reading a file. So if the buffer is wrong format, how should I read the file so I can do what I want.

Comment: Not sure why you expect `i[1]` to be `16`, can you explain?

Comment: "*accessing `i[0]` would return the integer represented by the first four bytes of the buffer, `i[1]` would return the integer represented by the second four bytes, and so on.*" - it does! Is that not what you are experiencing? What is happening instead? However, notice that how exactly the four bytes represent an integer depends on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the platform you are running this code on. If you want to share the files across machines, or even comply with a certain file format standard, you'll need to use a `DataView` and specific endianness.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote 16, but it could at least be non zero, because there is a 1 within those 4 bytes, but I am getting zero. It's like Int32Array doesn't change anything and acts like the same as underlying buffer. And it's length is the same as underlying buffer. I ended up using `buffer.getInt32LE(4)` to access the second integer so it works. But I don't understand why DataView doesn't work.

Comment: Does `expect(i.length).toBe(8 / 4)` actually hold? I'd expect that to throw, `i.length` should be 8 with your code. And only `i[4]` would be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `b` is a [nodejs `Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), not an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer). Unlike the name suggests, `Buffer` [is actually an `Uint8Array` subclass](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-typedarrays) and behaves like one.

In your case, constructing a `new Int32Array(b)` did not create a view on the buffer but actually iterated it and created one new `int32` value from each byte - giving `i` a `.length` of 8 and a `.byteLength` of 32.

To get integers represented by 4 bytes of the buffer each, you'll need to use `let i = new Int32Array(b.buffer);`.